# Finding roots of complex equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

Determine all roots of the equation $x^6+(3+i)x^3 + 3i = 0$ in $\mathbb{C}$ Express answers in standard form

Comment: Since you're (somewhat) new here, I'd like remind you that it would help if you show what you have already tried. This lets us know where you got stuck, and allows us to better answer your question.  Also, showing your work demonstrates that you have invested some time in the problem, which increases the likelihood of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (one per question) if you find it helpful. You can also upvote every answer you find helpful ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quadratic in $z^3$. solve for $z^3$, using the Quadratic formula, though in this case "factoring" will also work.

Then take cube roots in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^3 = z$. We then have that
$$z^2 + (3+i)z + 3i = 0 \implies (z+3)(z+i) = 0 \implies z = -3, -i \implies x^3 = -3,-i$$
Hence,
$$x = \sqrt[3]{-3},\sqrt[3]{-3} \omega, \sqrt[3]{-3} \omega^2, i, i\omega, i\omega^2$$where $\omega$ is the complex cube-root of $1$ and $\sqrt[3]{-3}$ is the real number $y$ such that $y^3 = -3$.